# Taxonomy related query not working

Tags: wp-query, custom-field

For all of my pages I have setup a taxonomy field using the plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/), for which I can then select as `Home` category, or something else like `News`. I am using the default category option, not a custom taxonomy.

I have a custom post type `slides_post_type` where for each new `slide` I am selecting the relevant category, i.e. `Home`.

The code I am using at present to output the slides is:

```
<?php
$slides_category = get_field('slider_category');
$args = array(-
'post_type' => 'slides_post_type',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'slug',   
        'terms'    => array( $slides_category ),
    ),
),    
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$my_secondary_loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $my_secondary_loop->have_posts() ): while( $my_secondary_loop->have_posts() ): $my_secondary_loop->the_post(); ?>
    //Post content goes here
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This should be that where my page is set to `Home` and my slides are set to the same category it should show those `slides`. However this code is not outputting anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your taxonomy field storing slugs? Also you're creating 2 new queries but only using one, I suggest reading WP_Query codex page thoroughly.

Comment: Is the `-` in this line `$args = array(-` just a typo. Also, the value stored in `slider_category`, does that match the **slug** or **name** of the category. If the value in your field matches the name of the category, your query won't work

Comment: The extra '-' wad a mistake and I changed the field value to 'id' and it worked. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The final code I used was:

```
<?php
$slides_category = get_field('slider_category');
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'slides_post_type',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => array( $slides_category ),
        ),
    ),
);
$slides_loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $slides_loop->have_posts() ): while( $slides_loop->have_posts() ): $slides_loop->the_post(); ?>
     // Post content goes here
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `wp_reset_query()` after first query, on 3th code line `$args = array(-   clear extra -`

Comment: Please properly format your code, and explain **why** this would help the OP solve his problem

Comment: Thank you Computer Information but having tried your solution it did not work, and although I am no real coder I cannot see how inserting the reset command after the first query would make much of a difference.